# Extract data from a large and nested JSON file using PHP JsonReader

Tags: php, json, csv

I am trying to extract data from a large and nested JSON file using PHP JsonReader, and put it in a `.csv`. My problems are:

1. Print out the keys that starts with `foo_` in a column
2. Print out other object values in the nested file

My desired CSV table is [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0MjygvBH6bsclJoaFpKOUhFYW8/view?usp=sharing). Somehow, I am not getting desired result, but I know I have an idea. Here is [my dummy file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0MjygvBH6bsdTN5eHJoZHZMeG8/view?usp=sharing).

Here is my code:

```
<?php
require_once 'C:/xampp/htdocs/json/pcrov/vendor/autoload.php';
use \pcrov\JsonReader\JsonReader;
ini_set("max_execution_time", 0);
$reader = new JsonReader();
$reader->open("jsonfile.json");
$fo = fopen("csvfile.csv", "w" );
fputs($fo, "name, companyID, ultimateHoldingCompany".PHP_EOL);
while ($reader->read(strpos($key, "foo__"))) {
    // I want to loop through the key that contains foo_ and print the key name
    $companyID = null;
    $entityName = null;
    $uhc = null;
    $companyID = $key
    $entityName = $reader->value();
    $UltimateHoldingCompany = $reader['ultimateHoldingCompany']['name']-
    >value;
    fputs($fo, 
    $entityName.",".$companyID.",".$UltimateHoldingCompany.PHP_EOL);
   }
  $reader->close();
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the code below using this [dummy jsonfile](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0MjygvBH6bsdTN5eHJoZHZMeG8/view?usp=sharing), and it answers perfectly the question I posted.

```
 <?php
 require_once 'C:/xampp/htdocs/json/pcrov/vendor/autoload.php'; //make sure 
 that this is a correct file path
 use \pcrov\JsonReader\JsonReader;
 ini_set("max_execution_time", 0);
 $reader = new JsonReader();
 $reader->open("jsonfile.json");
 $fo = fopen("csvfile.csv", "w" );
 fputs($fo, "name, companyID, uhc".PHP_EOL);
 {
     if (preg_match('/^foo_/', $reader->name())){ //To retreive keys that 
 // starts with `foo_`, wildcard is employed here using regular expression 
 // function in php. 
    $companyID = $reader->name();
    $companyID1 = str_ireplace("foo_","",$companyID); // this line is 
 // necessary in order to remove foo_ because what is needed in the output 
 // is everything after `foo_`.

    if ($reader->read("entityName")){
        $entityName = $reader->value();
        $entityName = str_ireplace(","," ",$entityName); //comma need to be 
 // replaced because csv treats comma as a delimiter. if comma not removed, 
 // csv pushes everything after comma to another column
    }

    if ($reader->read("ultimateHoldingCompany")){       
        $uhcName = null;
        $uhc = $reader->value();
        if (empty($uhc)){
        }
        else {
            $uhcName = $uhc[0]['name'];
            $uhcName = str_ireplace(","," ",$uhcName); //comma need to be 
 // replaced because csv treats comma as a delimiter. if comma not removed, 
 // csv pushes everything after comma to another column
        }

    }       

    fputs($fo,  $companyID1.",".$entityName.",".$uhcName.PHP_EOL);
    }   
  }
 $reader->close();
 ?>
```